# Python Socket - Can't connect a second time

Tags: python, sockets, reconnect

I have set up a socket server with a client and a host.
It works fine until the client has disconnected, with both .shutdown() and .close().
When I then launch the client again, it can't connect.
I presume this is not because of *how* I've written my code but rather what I *haven't* written.

How do I make the server truly disconnect the client's connection so that it can connect again?

Server:

```
import socket, threading, time, json

ONLINE_USERS = []
SESSION = None

class User():
    def __init__(user, connection, address):
        print('for', address, '{Connection established}')
        user.connection = connection
        user.address = address
        user.character = None
        threading.Thread(target=user.process, args=(), daemon=True).start()

    def process(user):
        time.sleep(1)

        user.send("&pLogin\n^^^^^\n")
        username = user.send("&iUser>")
        password = user.send("&iPass>")
        print(user.ping())
        print(user.logout())

    def send(user, *x):
        user.connection.sendall(str.encode(str(x)))
        data = user.connection.recv(1024)
        return data if data!=b'\x01' else True

    def recv(user, x):
        user.connection.recv(x)

    def ping(user):
        start = time.time()
        user.connection.sendall(b'\x02')
        end = float(user.connection.recv(1024))
        return round((end - start) * 1000)

    def logout(user):
        user.connection.sendall(b'\x04')
        return user.connection.recv(4)


class Session():
    def __init__(session, host='', port=12345):
        session.host = host
        session.port = port
        session.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        session.socket.bind((host, port))
        session.socket.listen(10)

        def accept():
            conn = User(*session.socket.accept())
        session.thread_accept = threading.Thread(target=accept, args=(), daemon=True).start()

    def shutdown():
        for user in ONLINE_USERS.keys():
            ONLINE_USERS[user].connection.sendall(bytes([0xF]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SESSION = Session()
    input('Press heart to continue!\n')
```

Client:

```
import socket, sys, threading, time, os


def clear(t=0.5):
    time.sleep(t)
    os.system('cls')

def tryeval(x, default):
    try:
        return eval(x)
    except:
        return default


class Client():
    def __init__(client):
        try:
            server_info = input('IP_ADDRESS:PORT>').split(':')
            client.host = server_info[0]
            client.port = int(server_info[1])
        except:
            client.host = 'localhost'
            client.port = 12345

        client.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.socket.settimeout(10)

        try:
            client.socket.connect((client.host, client.port))
            clear()
            client.data_exchange()

        finally:
            client.shutdown()

    def data_exchange(client):
        while True:
            data = client.socket.recv(1024)

            if data:
                if data==b'\x02':
                    client.socket.sendall(str.encode(str(time.time())))
                elif data==b'\x04':
                    client.shutdown()

                else:
                    data = tryeval(data, ())
                    response = []

                    for item in data:
                        try:
                            prefix, content = item[:2], item[2:]
                            if prefix=='&p':
                                print(content, end='')
                            elif prefix=='&i':
                                response.append(input(content))
                            if prefix=='&c':
                                time.sleep(float(content))
                                clear()
                        except:
                            pass

                    if len(response)>0:
                        client.socket.sendall(str.encode(str(tuple(response))))
                    else:
                        client.socket.sendall(b'\x01')


            time.sleep(0.001)

    def shutdown(client):
        try:
            client.socket.sendall(b'\x04')
        except:
            pass
        print('Shutting down program.')
        client.socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        print('Socket has been shutdown.')
        client.socket.close()
        print('Socket has been closed.')
        print('Exiting program')
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client()
```

Comment: do you get error message ? always in question show FULL error message (Traceback)

Comment: How many times does your server call accept?

Comment: I don't get any error messages. If you were to run the server and the client it works. Then closing the client and opening it again, it never connects, nothing happens.
The server repeatedly calls accept waiting for new incoming connections. Under Session you have this:
`def accept():
            conn = User(*session.socket.accept())
session.thread_accept = threading.Thread(target=accept, args=(), daemon=True).start()`

Comment: "The server repeatedly calls accept waiting for new incoming connections."  No it doesn't.  It calls `accept` once in a thread...which exits.

Comment: Whoops... How could I have missed that? x) Thanks for pointing it out. It works now. A bit embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

"The server repeatedly calls accept waiting for new incoming connections." No it doesn't. It calls `accept` once in a thread...which exits. – Mark Tolonen

Comment: Since it was just an oversight on my part, should I delete the post so that someone else doesn't come here looking for an answer and it's actually quite irrelevant?